# Hiveserver2 failed to open new session in beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I'm running hive 2.1.1, hadoop 2.7.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

`ps aux | grep hive` shows that hiveserver2 is running.

I'm trying to login with user [hive2] and password [password] to hivesever2 through beeline.

Here is my beeline output:

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: 
17/02/14 13:51:41 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: server is not allowed to impersonate anonymous (state=08S01,code=0)
```

I am able to connect to the embedded mode by entering `!connect jdbc:hive2://` in beeline.

Here's my hive-site.xml:

```
 <configuration>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
         <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;useSSL=false</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
         <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
         <value>hive</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
         <value>password</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>beeline.hs2.connection.user</name>
         <value>hive2</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>beeline.hs2.connection.password</name>
         <value>password</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>beeline.hs2.connection.hosts</name>
         <value>localhost:10000</value>
     </property>

 </configuration>
```

I removed beeline-hs2-connection.xml in case it will overwrite hive-site.xml.

Here's my core-site.xml

```
 <configuration>
     <property>
         <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>hadoop.proxyuser.centos.groups</name>
         <value>*</value>
     </property>

     <property>
         <name>hadoop.proxyuser.centos.hosts</name>
         <value>*</value>
     </property>

 </configuration>
```

How could I fix the error and connect to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any `proxyuser` entries in `core-site.xml`?

Comment: Hey, franklinsijo, I leave * as the value. I add the core-site.xml into the question.

Comment: You are trying to login to beeline as which user? `server`?

Comment: user: hive2, password: password.

Comment: Add that user as proxyuser in `core-site.xml` properties, `hadoop.proxyuser.hive2.groups`, `hadoop.proxyuser.hive2.hosts` and see if it solves. Add these properties in addition to what is already present.

Comment: Could I just use * as the value for hadoop.proxyuser.hive2.groups and hadoop.proxyuser.hive2.hosts?

Comment: Yes. `* ` as value is fine since this is local environment.

Comment: I added those properties into core-site.xml and restart hadoop, hiveserver2. The same error still occurs in beeline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135718/discussion-between-franklinsijo-and-top-deck).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> User: server is not allowed to impersonate anonymous

Here `server` is the user which is attempting to impersonate `anonymous` user.

Add these properties to `core-site.xml` and restart the services.

```
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.hosts</name> 
     <value>*</value> 
</property> 
<property>
     <name>hadoop.proxyuser.server.groups</name>
     <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Franklinsijo, you actually spend almost 2 hours for helping me! Really appreciate!

Comment: thank you... this answer was very helpful to me.